# Raster to polygon tool not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon, raster-conversion

I am trying to convert a raster to polygon in ArcGIS 10.2.2 but when I run the tool, it says complete but no polygon file is created and the tool window pops up again. I have tried converting the raster to integer type, but still no luck! I am using a raster projected from Mollweide projection to GCS WGS 1984 and both the input raster and output location is in a geodatabase.

Comment: this looks like a bug and you do not provide enough information to solve your problem. What is your coordinate system ? have you tried on a subset of your raster.what version of arcgis are you using? what is the output type (tif, grid, geodatabase ?)...Please edit your question with as much details as possible.

Comment: We still don't have enough detail to offer much assistance. Can you provide the python snippet from the tool results?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but if anyone else runs into this - I had the same issue and my problem was that I was trying to save the polygon with the same name as the raster in the same geodatabase. I changed the name of the output polygon and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  I'm unclear quite what you mean here - how can you save the polygon with the same name as the raster in the same database?  You can't have two objects with the same name in a database.  Can you [edit] your answer to give some more details?